# Installed Xenial on Mac Mini mid-2011. No options in EFI boot menu

Tags: boot, mac, boot-repair, grub-efi, mac-mini

The install went well. I've had to download b43updated.zip with firmware for the wireless network card, otherwise it's fine except for one other issue:

1. Ubuntu boots
2. Alt during boot doesn't show anything else except "Macintosh HD" and one other standard entry.
3. When I change boot order with `sudo efibootmgr -o 80, 0, ffff`, then it's OS X that boots, and the boot menu still shows "Macintosh HD", no other entry

So Ubuntu is available for boot, I can make it first OS. But it is not available for selection during boot. What can be done?

Comment: I've got a similar problem with a Macmini4,1 / 2010 Mac Mini.  Alt doesn't work, however after installation, I rebooted twice, and for some reason it landed  me into Ubuntu.  Keeping my fingers crossed that it keeps booting linux.